# Cannot run Bundle Install on Mac OS Mountain Lion due to JSON v(1.7.3) gem error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

first thing is first, I HAVE the command line tools from xcode installed on my mac, so that is not the issue. Please don't point me to the 50 other posts about this, as they all just say "install the command line tools".

This is the error I get when I run `bundle install`

```
Installing json (1.7.3) with native extensions 
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
creating Makefile

make
compiling parser.c
make: gcc-4.2: No such file or directory
make: *** [parser.o] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/json-1.7.3 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/json-1.7.3/ext/json/ext/parser/gem_make.out
An error occured while installing json (1.7.3), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install json -v '1.7.3'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I've been looking all over the place, and some people have told me to install the `install ruby-dev` command, but I haven't found a mac solution, as I don't have `apt-get` installed.

Besides, looking at the error, it looks like there is a directory missing where the files are trying to go. I'm not sure what to even do about that?

I haven't been able to find a way to reinstall ruby altogether either.

Any easy solutions to this?

Thanks a ton!

EDIT: Here is a list of my local gems, I am running GCC version 4.2.1, and Ruby version 1.9.3-p194

What's wierd is that there is already a newer version of JSON installed (1.7.5), so I don't know why it's trying to install 1.7.3, maybe there is a gem that has a dependency? I wish I could just skip that gem, and install the rest of the bundle. The dependency should be met with 1.7.5, unless a gem is calling for a specific version, right?

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionmailer (3.2.13, 3.2.7, 3.2.6)
actionpack (3.2.13, 3.2.7, 3.2.6)
activemodel (3.2.13, 3.2.7, 3.2.6)
activerecord (3.2.13, 3.2.7, 3.2.6)
activeresource (3.2.13, 3.2.7, 3.2.6)
activesupport (3.2.13, 3.2.7, 3.2.6)
appscrolls (0.9.0, 0.8.4)
arel (3.0.2)
bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1)
bourne (1.4.0, 1.2.1)
builder (3.2.0, 3.0.0)
bundler (1.3.4, 1.1.5)
coffee-rails (3.2.2)
coffee-script (2.2.0)
coffee-script-source (1.6.1, 1.3.3)
comp_tree (1.1.3)
devise (2.2.3, 2.1.2)
draper (1.1.0)
erubis (2.7.0)
execjs (1.4.0)
factory_girl (4.2.0)
factory_girl_rails (4.2.1)
hike (1.2.1)
i18n (0.6.4, 0.6.1, 0.6.0)
journey (1.0.4)
jquery-rails (2.2.1, 2.1.1, 2.0.2)
js-routes (0.8.7)
json (1.7.5)
mail (2.5.3, 2.4.4)
metaclass (0.0.1)
mime-types (1.21, 1.19)
mocha (0.13.3, 0.12.7)
multi_json (1.7.1, 1.3.6)
orm_adapter (0.4.0)
polyglot (0.3.3)
pure (0.2.2)
rack (1.5.2, 1.4.5, 1.4.1)
rack-cache (1.2)
rack-ssl (1.3.3, 1.3.2)
rack-test (0.6.2, 0.6.1)
rails (3.2.13, 3.2.7, 3.2.6)
railties (3.2.13, 3.2.7, 3.2.6)
rake (10.0.3, 0.9.2.2)
rdoc (4.0.0, 3.12)
request_store (1.0.5)
ruby_parser (3.1.2)
rubygems-bundler (1.1.1, 1.0.3)
rvm (1.11.3.6, 1.11.3.5)
sass (3.2.7, 3.2.1, 3.1.20)
sass-rails (3.2.6, 3.2.5)
sexp_processor (4.2.0)
shoulda (3.4.0)
shoulda-context (1.0.2)
shoulda-matchers (1.5.1, 1.5.0)
simple_form (2.1.0, 2.0.2)
sprockets (2.9.0, 2.2.2, 2.1.3)
sqlite3 (1.3.6)
state_machine (1.1.2)
thor (0.17.0, 0.16.0, 0.15.4)
tilt (1.3.6, 1.3.3)
treetop (1.4.12, 1.4.10)
tzinfo (0.3.37, 0.3.33)
uglifier (1.3.0, 1.2.7)
warden (1.2.1)
```

Comment: Which `xcode` and `gcc` version do you have installed? Have you tried updating your `json gem`? (current version is 1.7.8)

Comment: before, I had GCC version 4.2.1 installed. Could xcode just need updated to 4.6.1?

Comment: okay, xcode is up to 4.6.1 now, but still no luck. GCC is version 4.2.1 like I said, and that's the most up to date one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you don't have GCC installed. There are at least three ways to get it:

1. Go the App Store. Install Xcode. Then, in Xcode, choose Xcode > Preferences > Downloads and click install beside the Command Line Tools.
2. Log in to the Apple Developer site, go to the [downloads page](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action) and download the command line tools disk image. Install.
3. Install GCC via homebrew, macports or by compiling it from scratch.

Comment: Awesome, im installing homebrew now and seeing how that works. But if you are saying GCC should have come installed with the Command Line Tools, it didnt, as I've installed them BOTH from the Downloads panel in XCode and from the Apple Developers site, with no luck either way.

Comment: The Command Line tools do install GCC — `/usr/bin/gcc` is a symlink to `llvm-gcc-4.2`. It looks like the json make script is explicitly calling gcc-4.2. Try symlinking `/usr/bin/gcc` to `/usr/bin/gcc-4.2`.